# Feed me: set entrytype dynamically

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme, import

Can someone confirm that when importing entries with Feed-Me, the entrytype can NOT be set dynamically based on a field of the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think it is possible via GUI but you can do this via feed me [events](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/developers/events.html#the-stepbeforeelementsave-event) and a simple plugin.

because entrytype's fieldlayout and field mappings are different, in my solution, you should edit feed and update fieldmapping for each entry type, change the if condition of the code and run the feed again.

```
    Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE, function (FeedProcessEvent $event) {
        $entryTypeId=$event->feedData['entrytype'];
        if ($entryTypeId==1){
            $event->element->typeId=1;
        }
        //maybe, if field mapping for entrytype1 and entrytype2 are same
        elseif ($entryTypeId==2){
            $event->element->typeId=2;
        } 
        else {
            //skip saving element for other entry types because they have different field mapping.
            $event->isValid=false;
        }
    });
```

- [about event->isValid](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/craft-3-preventing-element-from-saving-in-plugin)

Comment: Beware using this trick when trying to update entries. When FeedMe tries to find an existing element, it includes the entryType in the query, so it will create duplicate entries instead of updating the existing ones.